# How do I create an Excel formula that will progress through three different columns to return results and return "1" if all the columns are empty?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am attempting to create a formula that reviews three different columns of data and returns a result in ascending order.

I believe I should be able to do this with a nested IF statement, but perhaps I should be using an array (or I'm missing something that's going to make me feel stupid).

I need the formula to check Column A to see if there's a value there.  If there is, then return that.  If there isn't, then it should return Column B.  If there's nothing in both column A & Column B, then I want it to return Column C.  If there's nothing in all three, then return "1".

I've tried a number of variations of this formula, and it seems to work for the first two parts, but then stops.

=if(A2>0,A2,IF(A2=0,B2,IF(AND(A2=0,B2=0),C2,"1")))

Again, this feels like its going to be something obvious, but I've looked at dozens of articles and nothing seems to match.

I would really appreciate help finding the solution.

Best Regards

I included the formula that I tried.  I've tried it without the AND but I can't get it to work past the first two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1,IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(C1<>"",C1,1)))
```

[image]

The usual case is you need as many singles IF conditions as your different outputs minus 1. Because you got 4 different outputs then you need 3 IFS.

Comment: A variation of this solved things for me.  Thanks so much for your assistance!